# Excluding text files etc. from a backup application C#

Tags: c#, lambda, backup

```
private void btn_Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DirectoryInfo> SourceDir = this.lbox_Sources.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();
        List<DirectoryInfo> TargetDir = this.lbox_Targets.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo sourcedir in SourceDir)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo targetdir in TargetDir)
            {
                string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_H.mm.ss");
                string LogFileName = @"BackupLog_" + sourcedir.Name + @"_" + dateString + @".log";
                string[] lines = { dateString + "\t" + sourcedir.FullName + "\t" + targetdir.FullName + "\t" + "COMPLETED" };

                if (this.checkbox_zipfiles.Checked == true)
                {
                    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcedir.FullName, targetdir.FullName + @"\BACKUP_" + sourcedir.Name + @"_" + dateString + @".zip");
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(tbox_LogFiles.Text + @"\" + LogFileName, lines);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var file in sourcedir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourcedir.FullName, targetdir.FullName, true);
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(tbox_LogFiles.Text + @"\" + LogFileName, lines);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to exclude certain files from the backup (like .txt .docx)
I am using a list on my Form to add those exceptions.
I will also need to exclude certain Files and Folders but I think I can do that if I know how to do this.

```
private void btn_AddFileTypeException_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_FileTypeExceptions frm = new Form_FileTypeExceptions(new FileException());

        if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.lbox_FileTypeExceptions.Items.Add(frm.Exception);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: what is the structure of your FileException class? (btw, bad name for a collection of - i'm guessing - file extensions)

Comment: With the copy technique you have chosen, you are not looking at each file separately. I think you need to do that.

Comment: When you call sourcedir.GetFiles()... you can pass in the file extensions you want as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From form where you're setting extensions to be excluded fill list of strings that will contain extensions to skip, something like this:

```
List<string> extensionsToSkip = new List<string>();
extensionsToSkip.Add(".txt");
extensionsToSkip.Add(".docx");
//etc...
```

in your inner loop, change `foreach` loop from

```
foreach (var file in sourcedir.GetFiles())
```

into this

```
foreach (var file in sourcedir.GetFiles()
    .Where(f => !extensionsToSkip.Contains(f.Extension)).ToList())
```

as you can see, when you get file collection with `GetFiles` it will be filtered to exclude extensions specified in `extensionsToSkip` list.

before that mentioned loop, test if you're getting right number of files by observing there two lists (just for test):

```
var originalList = sourcedir.GetFiles();
var filteredList = sourcedir.GetFiles().Where(f => !extensionsToSkip.Contains(f.Extension)).ToList();
```